# What is the purpose of these strange patterns in i/o port panel of GPU card?

Tags: heatsink, reverse-engineering, pcie, mechanical, gpu

Ref: https://www.techspot.com/article/1988-anatomy-graphics-card/

1. The left side pattern seems to get it attached to [Graphics card slot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVbjl69z3HE)- but not sure why those flanges are required.
   [image]
2. Absolutely no idea of the other pattern -X shaped ? Is it for heat dissipation?

Comment: XFX is the manufacturer of the card.

Comment: I can move this to https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ if it doesn't belong here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Answer (score 2):

The flange, as well as the strip of metal at the bottom are standard for mounting PC add-in cards. The strip goes in a slot to secure the bottom. The top flange rests on top of a metal strip in the chassis and is either secured by a screw through the sideways opening (traditional chassis) or by a clamp (toolless chassis). Together, these guarantee that the the card cannot to forced from its connection slot in the motherboard, ether by vibration or the force of connecting cables.

As for the opening, that is the manufacturer’s name (XFX) cut into the metal.